# Cast an instance to its real type

Tags: java, class, casting

I have a method which invokes several other methods and these methods have different return types, just like:

```
public void caller() {
    String methodName = "call2";
    Method[] methods = Called.class.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method method : methods) {
        if (method.getName().equals(methodName)) {
            Object obj = method.invoke(null, null);
            // then I want to cast obj to its real type, in called class the 
            // method may return a List or Map an so on
        }
    }
}
```

for example method `a` returns a plant, method `b` returns an animal, method `c` returns a stone, I need to cast it to the real type so i can use the Unique

Comment: So what is the issue with it?

Comment: What do you mean, "cast it to its real type"?  It already is its real type.  If you know its type, you can cast it with `(List<Whatever>)` or the like; if you don't, then there's nothing you can do anyway.

Comment: Any particular reason you aren't using [`getDeclaredMethod(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29)?

Comment: would an interface work for you?

Comment: @AnandSKumar  I want cast it to its real class not declared class, just like <code>Animal animal = new Dog()<code> I declared An animal but It`s a DOG indeed , so I can use methods in DOG  not in Animal and If I use instanceof  If there is a lot animal dog cat monkey and so on I should if...else a lot I want a way cast automatic

Comment: @user1133275 a interface ? they don`t have a superclass interface except super class Object

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Comment: @Wangbo I'm asking why you don't just wrap all the objects in subclasses that implement an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume from your example, `Dog`, `Cat` are children of `Animal` class.

```
class Animal{}
class Dog extends Animal{}
class Cat extends Animal{}
```

You can use generics to get cast any `children` of `Animal` object cast to `Animal`:

```
public <T extends Animal> Animal castToAnimal(T childAnimal) {
    Animal animal = null;
    if (childAnimal != null) {
        animal = Animal.class.cast(childAnimal);
        // Or use
        // animal = (Animal) childAnimal;
    }
    return animal;
}
```

As defined `castToAnimal` method accepts only `children` of `Animal` class as argument, so that you can avoid `instanceof` check.

Comment: It`s pretty cool through I express my issue not clear, but your comment  inspired me tkx

Comment: Note this cast is a check. The reference starts as an Animal and ends up as an Animal type. Ie if it is an Animal it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to cast it to it's real type if you are going to use it for something such as

```
if (obj instanceof Map) {
    Map map = (Map) obj;
    System.out.println("Size: "+map.size();

} else if (obj instanceof Collection) {
    Collection coll = (Collection) obj;
    System.out.println("Size: " + coll.size();

} else if ....
```

Note: you need to know all the types you might be interested in, at least broadly.

Comment: sorry,  that`s my fault ,I know this Way , but  I want a way to make extensible way  to do this

Comment: @Wangbo can you give an example of what you wan tot do with this object after casting that you cannot do without it?

Comment: Object is super class it doesn`t have List or Map or any other extends class method I need to use it your answer is regular way to cast an instance , but i want a way to cast it automatic just like <code>Animal animal = new Dog()</code> I declare an Animal but it`s a dog  indeed , so I can you the mothod declare in DOG not in Animal

Comment: perhaps this Comment is not correct please see Text of  this question for more detail